# Django - ValueError at / The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django

I am working on Django project I receive the following error:
"ValueError at / The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it."
models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Catagory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'Catagories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    Catagory = models.ForeignKey(Catagory, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description =models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_images', blank=True, null=True)
    is_sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

html

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5>{{ item.name }}</h5>
                            <p class="text-secondary">Price: {{ item.price }}</p>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Error during template rendering
How can I handle this error

Comment: Have you tried to first upload an image and then check? i think there is no image stored in the database that is why this error is occurring. you can have an ```if``` condition such that if there is no image stored in the database then it doesn't use the ```<img src>``` tag

Answer (score 0):

The error message should be very informative and self-explanatory.
Since your model allows an object to have no image, you must handle this in your template. You can not access `url` of `item.image` if there is no image at all.

You can use an simple if statement to check for an image:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    {% if item.image %}
        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5>{{ item.name }}</h5>
        <p class="text-secondary">Price: {{ item.price }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```